# Unable to install 'weak' module through npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, prerender

I'm trying to setup prerender.io with node express server but getting problem in setting up on my system. I'm using windows 10 and installed nodejs to use npm package.I installed prerenderjs , node server and phantomjs to start SEO with node express server. 
when I run 'node server.js' it gives following error for missing module 'weak' which is I think some dependency for running prerender.io.

```
2015-10-20T07:50:10.331Z worker 32 died, restarting!
2015-10-20T07:50:10.768Z starting phantom on port [12334]
2015-10-20T07:50:10.783Z starting phantom on port [12333]
2015-10-20T07:50:10.807Z starting phantom on port [12335]
2015-10-20T07:50:10.866Z Server running on port 3000
2015-10-20T07:50:10.866Z Server running on port 3000
2015-10-20T07:50:10.866Z Server running on port 3000
2015-10-20T07:50:11.018Z starting phantom on port [12336]
2015-10-20T07:50:11.043Z Server running on port 3000
module.js:338
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'weak'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at new D (C:\prerender-master\node_modules\phantom\node_modules\dnode\index.js:28:20)
at module.exports (C:\prerender-master\node_modules\phantom\node_modules\dnode\index.js:8:12)
at C:\prerender-master\node_modules\phantom\phantom.js:159:13
at Server.handler (C:\prerender-master\node_modules\phantom\node_modules\shoe\index.js:22:9)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Server.emit (events.js:169:7)
2015-10-20T07:50:12.209Z worker 34 died, restarting!
```

then I tried to install 'weak' through npm like

```
npm install weak
```

but its giving following error

```
npm WARN package.json prerender@3.22.1 No license field.
-
> weak@1.0.0 install C:\prerender-master\node_modules\weak
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\prerender-master\node_modules\weak>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-    bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v3.5.0, which is not     supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion (C:\Program     Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:121:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:110:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:194:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"   "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\prerender-master\node_modules\weak 
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program     Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "weak"
npm ERR! node v4.1.0 
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! weak@1.0.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the weak@1.0.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the weak package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls weak
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\prerender-master\npm-debug.log
```

I also tried npm install node-gyp and then again tried to install 'weak' but same error. I searched for the error but unable to understand the solutions. I'll be very thankful for any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v3.5.0, which is
>   not     supported by gyp. gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python
>   switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.

Looks like you just need to supply a different version of Python

Comment: I have the same error on node.js server even i am not using phantomjs. But node.js server is throwing an error of `cannot find module 'weak'`. It's causing this error on Aws Ec2 instance. On local machine it's working fine but throwing an error on Aws EC2. I have python 2.7.15rc1 on Aws Ec2. How can i solve it?